# FaceTime & Continuity: move call started from iPhone to Mac or vice versa

Tags: macos, ios, facetime, continuity

I received a FaceTime video call on my iPhone 6s (iOS 10.3.1) and I wanted to continue it on my MacBook Pro (macOS Sierra 10.12.4). Both devices were in the same WLAN and with Bluetooth turned on but I couldn't fine a way to transfer the call.

I was able to exploit Continuity with other apps, such as Safari and Mail, during the call but apparently not with FaceTime.

Is there a way to do so? or should I ask Apple to insert it in the next OS release?

Comment: Nope. I'd assume seamlessly handing off video rendering and peer to peer connections would be hard to implement.

Comment: I would send Apple [feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) and select _Enhancement Request_ as your feedback type. I suspect though that at present @IronCraftMan is correct, but it's something that will be possible in the future.